# Recordset.Filter for a string field does not work for the value of a control

Tags: ms-access, vba

The two items of interest are `[JobNum]` and `Me!JobID.Value`. When I keep it like below (where `me!JobID` is a textbox on the form), `rsFiltered` returns 0 records. But if I replace `Me!JobID.Value` to `"1000-3234"`, it returns the expected 5. Is there a reason why referencing the control value doesn't work? Even when I declare a string variable and set it equal to `Me!JobID.Value` and use that it still doesn't work.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rsFiltered As Recordset
Dim strQuery As String

strQuery = "SELECT Estimate.JobNum, Magnet.Sequence, Magnet.StartDate, Magnet.EndDate, Magnet.WeekendWork FROM Estimate RIGHT JOIN Magnet ON Estimate.ID = Magnet.[EstimateID];"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
rs.Filter = "[JobNum]=" & Me!JobID.Value
Set rsFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: What event runs this code?

Comment: Why not SELECT only the Filter? Why do you want to apply a filter after the JOIN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"1000-3234" is a string, thus:

```
rs.Filter = "[JobNum] = '" & Me!JobID.Value & "'"
```

Answer (score 2):

AS Gustav answer you need to filter your code like that and also I think you should use `.Text` property instead of `.Value`:

```
rs.Filter = "[JobNum] = '" & Me!JobID.Text & "'"
```

- [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173476%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

> The Text property returns the formatted string. The Text property may be different than the Value property for a text box control. The Text property is the current contents of the control. The Value property is the saved value of the text box control. The Text property is always current while the control has the focus.

And I think in this case `.Text` can make more sense.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think `.Text` should be used over `.Value`?

Comment: @Newd I add a detail, don't forgot OP use a textbox for filtering that may not saved ;).

Comment: The `.Text` property is only available when the control has focus. If anything else has focus, attempting to access `.Text` will throw an error. For example, if his code is for the click event of a command button, the button has focus when the code runs. He could use `Me!JobID.SetFocus` first to avoid the error.

Comment: Personally I have found `.Value` works 99.9% of the time, the only time I have had to use it is when I don't leave a field before I use an event to run code.  Such as the KeyPress event.